# Does Veda Consulting's dedupe workflow extension work on 4.7? Or is it now in Core?

Tags: extension, duplicate-contacts, workflow

Does Veda Consulting's [dedupe workflow UI extension](http://www.vedaconsulting.co.uk/civicrm-dedupe-workflow-ui),which looks really cool,  work on Civi 4.7, Drupal 7?

and if so, from where and how exactly do I install/git clone it? The latest commits are at 
https://github.com/veda-consulting/civicrm-core/compare/4.5...veda-consulting:dedupe-workflow-45

Or is the functionality now in Core for 4.7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think this pull request, that was merged into 4.7, contains at least some of these improvements. But not the functionality from the extension (as far as I know):

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6432

Check out the new functionality on the demo site, and see if it meets your expectations.

http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: @JoeMcLaughlin any word on what you found?

Comment: JonG I have not nailed anything definite down nor tried updating since I posted this last year.. We're still on 4.6.19